# Swing Actions - Linking Menus and Toolbar

Tags: java, swing

I've been studying Java Swing and I'm working on learning actions.
I can successfully create action objects and use them to link items from a `JToolBar` to `JMenuItems`. **My problem, is that the constructed actions display both icons *and* text in the toolbar (should only be the icons)**.
Check out the following code:

```
import java.awt.*;    
import java.awt.event.*;  
import javax.swing.*;  

class MenuDemo{  

   MenuDemo(){  
      JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("Complete Menu Demo");  
      jfrm.setSize(220, 200);  
      jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  

      JMenuBar jmb = new JMenuBar();  

      /* Make the action object */  
      ImageIcon setIcon = new ImageIcon("setBP.png");  
      DebugAction setAct = new DebugAction("Set Breakpoint",   
                                         setIcon, KeyEvent.VK_S,   
                                         KeyEvent.VK_B, "Set Breakpoint");  

      /* Make the toolbar */  
      JButton jbtnSet    = new JButton(setAct);  
      JToolBar jtb = new JToolBar("Breakpoints");  
      jtb.add(jbtnSet);  

      /* Make the menu */  
      JMenu jmDebug = new JMenu("Debug");  
      JMenuItem jmiSetBP = new JMenuItem(setAct);  
      jmDebug.add(jmiSetBP);  

      jmb.add(jmDebug);  
      jfrm.getContentPane().add(jtb, BorderLayout.NORTH);  
      jfrm.setJMenuBar(jmb);  
      jfrm.setVisible(true);  
   }  

   class DebugAction extends AbstractAction{  
     public DebugAction(String name, Icon image, int mnem,  
                         int accel, String tTip){  
        super(name, image);  

        putValue(ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(accel,  
                 InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));  
        putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, new Integer(mnem));  
        putValue(SHORT_DESCRIPTION, tTip);  
     }  

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){  
     }  
   }  

   public static void main(String[] args){  
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){  
         public void run(){  
           new MenuDemo();  
         }  
      });  
   }  
}
```

---

This program yields the following GUI:

[image: Screenshot of GUI with Text in JToolbar Icon]   [image: Screenshot of GUI with Menu Showing]

I just want the green button in the `JToolBar`, not text. I think my problem code is in the `DebugAction` constructor, where I call `super(name, image)`. For the toolbar buttons, I would only want to pass in the image. But for the menu I want both. How can I "turn off" the text for the `JToolBar` items? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I "turn off" the text for the JToolBar items?

You turn it off using:

```
JButton button = new JButton( action );
button.setHideActionText( true );
```

Or, you can just reset the text on the button:

```
JButton button = new JButton( action );
button.setText("");
```

Comment: Someone give this guy a cookie! Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I accepted camickr's answer, but there is a caveat.

For identification purposes, I am grabbing the actionCommand of these buttons. Both `setHideActionText(true);` and `button.setText("")` do remove the text, but both produce errors when I try to grab the actionCommand.
To fix this, I explicitly set the actionCommand when I create the action object by adding the additional line in the constructor:

`putValue(ACTION_COMMAND_KEY, sometext);`

This fixed the errors.

Comment: Generally speaking, a Action is self contained, so needing the "text" or "ActionCommand" generally shouldn't need to be known

Comment: I've linked several of the components to the same actionListener, so I'm using the actionCommand to identify the JButton/JMenuItem selected.

Comment: In this particular case, I'm trying to avoid a bunch of different inner classes, by using one actionListener and linking to methods from there.
This may be bad form, but for my simple demo program it serves its purpose.

Comment: You are creating multiple `Action`s? Each `Action` has it's own `actionPerformed` method which is called when the action is triggered automatically. One of the reasons for using `Action` is so you don't need to have a "blob" `ActionListener`, which makes your code more modular and easier to manage. This is of course your choice, but perfect practice makes perfect